Check syntax of single fortran file
I am working with a large fortran codebase, and am making changes to one file in this. The build system is complex, must be run on a certain non-local computer, and is time consuming. I would like to check the syntax of the single fortran file I am editing, without having to do a full compile. What tools exist for doing this? Tool must be easily installable and runnable on linux.
So far I have tried https://github.com/cphyc/fortran-linter, but I cannot see how to output only syntax errors from this. And VS Code with fortran plugins, but my understanding is that the linter relies on third party compilers (e.g. gfortran and ifort), and it is difficult to set these up for my project due to the codebase complexity.
EDIT: This question How to use Fortran compilers to parse-check or pretty print source files? suggests using gfortran -fsyntax-only <file>, which is the kind of thing I'm looking for. However, it fails when I try it on one of my files: Fatal Error: Cannot open module file ‘<filename>.mod’. I.e. it won't work without being able to build the entire module dependency tree, which is huge.

What dialect and era of FORTRAN code is it? I'd have thought you could try compiling individual files but not linking them with any compiler that supports the right standard. Some syntax directed editors are fairly good too. I have a soft spot for the former Salford Fortran compiler now sold as Silverfrost FTN95. Depending on the size and portability of the total codebase and effort involved it might be worth porting it to your preferred local development environment.

Fortran 2003, but it is an old codebase and a lot of the files were originally fortran 90 (and some possibly older).

Do the file(s) you are modifying contain modules ? Or use modules ?

@PierU yes - they make heavy use of modules. This is part of the problem - see my edit.

OK... If your code have modules you have dependencies, so it gets difficult to compile a file out of the whole context of the project.

You could try satisfying it's request for the various missing .MOD files by putting them into the right search path. You aren't looking to build it for syntax checking - just satisfy the compiler enough to process one source file in isolation.  Might be worth a punt providing it with an empty file with the right name or one containing just a few of the prototypes for things it is meant to contain to see how much of it is actually essential.

Before you start modifying, do one complete build and get all the module files.  Then when you are making local modifications, you can just build that file and point to where all the module files are where modules are required.

@cup Fortran Modules are way after my time using Fortran seriously. I had assumed that they were somewhat like .DEF files in Modula 2 or .H files in C/C++. Prototypes for the methods, functions and abstract objects that the various modules promise to provide.  The intention being to allow a single source file to be compiled in isolation. It seems most odd to me that modules don't facilitate this in Fortran.

@MartinBrown .mod files are binary files generated by the compiler when encountering a MODULE programming unit in a source file, and are required when compiling other source files that USE the given module. It's quite different from an include file.

Depending on what you count as "syntax", you cannot hope to evaluate a single file by itself.  If you see a file like use mod; print *, [rea1 :: 1]; end, how do you intend to determine whether that's correct?

@PierU OK but that still seems like Modula 2 where the .DEF file is in plaintext describing the contents of a module that are available for export and their bindings and the .SYM file is a binary derived from it is required to compile anything intending to use that module. Basically a separation of Definition of what and Implementation of How. This means that you can compile module dependent source code without having the full potentially very large implementation of a  library implementation module you just have to have the definition binding .SYM files for type checking at compile time.

@MartinBrown There are pros and cons with the approach chosen for Fortran. One drawback is the "compilation cascade" like here (you can't compile an isolated file). One theoretical benefit is that the compiler has more freedom to define the binary interface.

I have a working solution. The build system is complex, but it does produce all of its <filename>.mod files in a predictable location. So whilst I can't easily modify the build system, I can copy the few files I am working on into the build source dirs, and then compile these relative to the existing .mod files. Many thanks to @cup for this suggestion. And to the other commenters for useful ideas/explanations of the fortran build system.
I see now why doing full syntax checking is impossible without compiling all dependency modules (thanks to @francescalus's example), but it seems to me that basic syntax checking should still be easy (misplaced "&"s, ","s etc). If anyone has ideas on this I'd still appreciate a new answer...
